# Zoom Image with ChangeView() - Windows Universal App - UWP Win10 - XAML

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I'm currently building a Windows Universal App in which I have a ScrollViewer that contains an Image. The goal is to zoom into the image when double tapping it. The zoom is supposed to be centered at the double tapped X/Y coordinates of the image.

**XAML**

```
<ScrollViewer Name="ImageScrollViewer" 
                VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" 
                VerticalScrollMode="Disabled" 
                HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" 
                HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled" 
                ZoomMode="Enabled" 
                MinZoomFactor="1" 
                DoubleTapped="scrollViewer_DoubleTapped"                              
                Grid.Row="1" 
                Grid.Column="3" 
                Grid.ColumnSpan="5" 
                Margin="5,5,5,5" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <Image x:Name="MainPageImage" 
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                    VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                    Stretch="None" 
                    d:IsLocked="False"/>
</ScrollViewer>
```

**Code Behind**

```
private void scrollViewer_DoubleTapped(object sender, DoubleTappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{      
  var doubleTapPoint = e.GetPosition(ImageScrollViewer);

  // zoom in
  if(zoomFactor == 1)
  {
    zoomFactor = 2;
    ImageScrollViewer.ChangeView(doubleTapPoint.X, doubleTapPoint.Y, zoomFactor);        
  }
  // zoom out
  else
  {
    zoomFactor = 1;
    // maxWidth and maxHeight are integer containing the maximum image size
    ImageScrollViewer.ChangeView(maxWidth, MaxHeight, zoomFactor);        
  } 
}
```

Now here's the problem: The image gets zoomed as desired, it always zooms to the top left corner of the Image. No matter where I double tapped it. The image coordinates are correctly read in the method - so I can pretty much exclude this as the source of the problem.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Derive from official document,

> Causes the ScrollViewer to load a new view into the viewport using the specified **offsets** and zoom factor.

The first and second parameter of `ChangeView` are horizontalOffset, verticalOffset that used scroll to content x or content y. But you have set `VerticalScrollBarVisibility` and `HorizontalScrollBarVisibility` disable. So the it always zooms to the top left corner of the Image.

For your requirement, you could use [`Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Animations`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Animations/) zoom your image directly.

```
using Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Animations;
private void scrollViewer_DoubleTapped(object sender, DoubleTappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var doubleTapPoint = e.GetPosition(ImageScrollViewer);

     // zoom in
    if (zoomFactor == 1)
    {
         zoomFactor = 2;

         MainPageImage.Scale(centerX: (float)doubleTapPoint.X,
                 centerY: (float)doubleTapPoint.Y,
                 scaleX: 2.0f,
                 scaleY: 2.0f,
                 duration: 500, delay: 0).StartAsync();


    }
     // zoom out
     else
    {
         zoomFactor = 1;
         MainPageImage.Scale(centerX: (float)doubleTapPoint.X,
                  centerY: (float)doubleTapPoint.Y,
                  scaleX: 1.0f,
                  scaleY: 1.0f,
                  duration: 500, delay: 0).StartAsync();

    }
}
```